# sending an email with example personalization string, stop Ampscript from interpreting the percent signs

Tags: ampscript

I want to send an email to our email users who create emails. I want to describe something about personalization strings. When I put the example in the content block (such as %%First Name%%) the Ampscript interpreter reads it (as expected). How can I include the example and have the interpreter not interpret it?
Thanks.
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Use the HTML entity for percent sign and it will display as you wish and not be recognized as a personalization string or ampscript.

% as HTML entity: `&#37;`

so for your example, you would do:

`&#37;&#37;First Name&#37;&#37;` and the email would show `%%First Name%%` and not show the actual person's first name.

[Reference](https://www.toptal.com/designers/htmlarrows/math/percent-sign/)